# Double click on apex:outputtext and show inputfield how can i implement this

Tags: apex, outputtext

**VisualForce Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="InlineEditingHelper">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title= "outputcomponents">
        <apex:outputPanel id="editfield">
            <apex:outputlabel value="Account Name (Double Click To Edit)   :  " for="Accname">
                <apex:actionSupport event="ondblclick" action="{!inlineEdit}" rerender="editfield"/>
            </apex:outputlabel>         
            <apex:outputText label="" value="{!Account.Name}" rendered="{!NOT(editmode)}" id="Accname"/>
            <apex:inputText label="" value="{!Account.Name}" rendered="{!editmode}" id="Accname2"/> 
        </apex:outputPanel>      
    </apex:pageBlock >
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller Extension**

```
public with sharing class InlineEditingHelper {
    public boolean editmode {get;set;}
    public InlineEditingHelper(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        editmode = false;
    }
    public void inlineEdit() {
        system.debug('entered here');
        editmode = true;
    }
}
```

I got this code but not able to implement  it on my reference

Comment: Are you facing any problem in your implementation or in understanding how it works? In case of your implementation, please paste you code, what you want and where you are stuck.

Comment: why don't you use salesforce standard functionality..  `<apex:outputField with inlineEditsupport`  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inlineEditSupport.htm

Comment: I  will not use outputfield because  i  have to show  property  and apex outputfield worked on  with sobject field   ex.   Integer count{get;set;}  show  with  outputtext and on dblclick  show inputtext field  thanks for your rply

Comment: @ArjunSFDC then you need to go with rerender solution.. Or javascript to show/ hide fields..

Comment: @Ratan  yes  Javascript code will help me  did you have any example ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efficient way to use actionsupport

[**Documentation:**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm)

```
public class InlineEditingHelper {

public String strName {get;set;}
public Boolean isEditable {get; private set;}

public InlineEditingHelper ()
{
 strName  = 'Test 1';
 isEditable = true;
}

public void changeEditable(){
  isEditable = isEditable ? false:true;
}
}
```

**VF page**

```
<apex:page Controller="InlineEditingHelper">
    <apex:form id="frm">
        <apex:pageBlock  id="pblock">

            <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbsection">
                <apex:outputpanel id="counter">
                   <apex:outputText value="{!strName }" rendered="{!isEditable }"/>
                   <apex:actionSupport event="ondblclick" action="{!changeEditable}"
                      rerender="frm" />
                </apex:outputpanel> 
                <apex:InputText value="{!strName }" rendered="{!!isEditable }">
                <apex:actionSupport event="ondblclick" action="{!changeEditable}"
                      rerender="frm" />
                </apex:InputText >
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: @ArjunSFDC glad it helped..

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="InlineEditingHelper">
  <apex:form>
     <script>
          function dblClick(){
              inEdit();
          }
      </script> 
    <apex:actionFunction name="inEdit" action="{!inlineEdit}" rerender="editfield" />  
    <apex:pageBlock title= "outputcomponents">
        <apex:outputPanel id="editfield">
            <apex:outputlabel value="Account Name (Double Click To Edit)   :  " />
            <apex:outputPanel id="editfieldIn" ondblclick="dblClick();" >
                <apex:outputText label="" value="test" id="Accname" rendered="{!NOT(editmode)}"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:inputText label="" value="{!Account.Name}" id="Accname2" rendered="{!editmode}"/> 
        </apex:outputPanel>  

    </apex:pageBlock >
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: ex. Integer count{get;set;} show with outputtext and on dblclick show inputtext field

Comment: just replace outputtext with outputField and remove the lable